# I need documentation about @PostAuthorize method in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.idea == authentication.idea.ideatorId")

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/ideaDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")

public ResponseEntity<?> editIdeaByIdeaId(@RequestBody final IdeaDTO idea) throws IOException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.facade.editIdeaByIdeaId(idea), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I write only the above code in my **controller** . The idea is the object of my Idea class and ideatorId is the id for one who creates the idea. My intention is to display only the idea details owned by a particular ideatorId. Is there any other configuration required to use @PostAuthorize or by simply write the above code.

Comment: Are you using the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` annotation?

( or if you use XML `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` )

Comment: where i would use this annotation. I cant find the XML file.

Comment: The XML is only if you use XML configuration, if you are using java configuration than you can put this annontation on any `@Configuration` class or your `@SpringBootApplication` class. also have a look at this link: 
https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/preauthorize-postauthorize-in-spring-security

Comment: @LaurenceMommers I found a package for prepost<br/> `package org.springframework.security.access.prepost;<br/>public @interface PostAuthorize {<br/>
 public String value();
}
`

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with this package. All you have to configure to use `@PostAuthorize` annotation is to enable it using the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` on your `@SpringBootApplication` class or any other  `@Configuration` class.

Comment: @LaurenceMommers  I done the configuration as `@EnableWebSecurity  
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)  
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}` and then i include  `@PostAuthorize("returnObject.idea == authentication.idea.ideatorId")` but i got **an error access** is denied

Comment: then it's working, now the access denied exception could be because a couple of reasons, check if you allow calls to the endpoint, and if you allow that than check if "returnObject.idea == authentication.idea.ideatorId" is the correct expression, with the given code, i would say that "authentication.idea.ideatorId" is not correct. maybe test with "returnObject.idea == 1" (or any other valid value)